# Wrong inverse function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: P(\mathbb{N})\to P(\mathbb{N})  $
$$f(A) = \{x|x-4\in A\}$$

What if the inverse function of this function?

I thought it's
$ g:P(\mathbb{N})\to P(\mathbb{N})  $ such that
$$g(A) = \{x|x\in A\}\cup\{x-4|x\in A\}$$

An example would be $f(\{5,1\})=\{5\}$, and $g(\{5\})=\{5,1\}$

But apparently this is not the correct answer.

What is my mistake?

Comment: $f(\{5,1\})=\{9,5\}$, no?

Comment: Inverse? But $f:\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\to\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ prescribed by $A\mapsto4+A$ is not surjective…

Comment: @lulu I guess you are right, I probably didn't understand well the function definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(A)=\{x: x+4 \in A\}$ just the set of points $x$ such that $x+4 $ is in $A$.